Would not God giving people a Commandment not to kill, but then commanding people to kill others, even innocents, be considered a contradiction?
I have been thinking lately how odd it is for God to give a Commandment to not kill, but then demand his followers to slay both animals and people, innocents even.
It did not have any exceptions like "Thou shall not kill  unless commanded to by me to.", just "Thou shall not kill".
So I feel this is contradiction. Is this correct?

The commandment is more likely "thou shall not murder"

Yeah, I heard that from others. Even so, killing innocents is murder, so it still is a contradiction imo. @eques

Well killing innocents would be a definition of murder, but that's not what your question asks. So the question is, do you actually want to engage in a good-faith discussion or are you looking for cheap shots to bolster your existing viewpoint?

YOU brought up that it was probably referring to murder, I said I heard about that take and said my point still stands as it goes against the given Commandment of no murder. Yes, I want a civil discourse. @eques

I brought up murder precisely because it is a counterpoint to the claim as you stated. You did not use the word murder. You mention innocent, but you don't actually articulate any evidence that the claimed "contradictions" are in regards innocents.

Fair enough, let me fetch some verses. @eques

"Killing innocents is murder"... which begs the question, is any creature "innocent"? Many Christians argue for "no".

The right to kill rests with God.  If God gives the order to kill then it is right to kill, and sinful not to kill.
In the case of the conquest of the Promised Land, God gave the order to the Israelites to destroy the inhabitants of the land because they were evil: they had been evil for four hundred years or so.  One of their biggest evils was sacrificing their 4 to 6 week old babies to their God, Baal and/or Molech.  The evidence of these sacrifices can be found today at Corinth, a Canaanite colony in Africa.  A graveyard there has thousands of skulls of 4 to 6 week old babies, and nothing else in that particular tophet-graveyard.  The babies were burned alive, the priests of Baal making a noise to mask their screams.. rather like today when aborted babies are killed hidden away from public gaze, having received no pain killers or sedation.
Another case where God requires a person to be killed is when a person has murdered another:

Whoever sheds the blood of man, by man shall his blood be shed. Genesis 9:6.

The chiasmic structure of the verse is intentional, to show it is just and right.. killing a murderer is proportionate to his crime.
God is not a soft, genial, cuddly, Father Christmas: He has appointed a Day when He will judge all the world, and punish with everlasting torment all who have continually rebelled against Him, and failed to repent and believe in the only Saviour.
The Lord Jesus was asked about the deaths of certain people because of a natural disaster. His reply was "Unless you repent you will all likewise perish." He was also asked about people who had been killed by another man.  Again, Jesus said, "Unless you repent, you will all likewise perish", Luke 13:1-5.
God brings death by natural means, and God judges by wicked hands also: God gives life, and God takes away what He has given. And the ungrateful receivers of all His blessings He will judge. The Israelites in the conquest of the Promised Land were God's executioners.
In the worship of Baal it was only the rich elite who were required to sacrifice some of their children, in "thanks" to their God for their privileged status, the poor people were not required to do so.  But we learn that what actually so often happened was that the rich would "adopt" a child from a poor family with a payment, and then sacrifice the adopted child, not their own.  In the light of this it is perhaps more fitting that the rich should witness the deaths of their own loved ones as retribution for their own wickedness against the poor.
If this aspect fails to satisfy our questioning of the justice of God's actions in killing all the inhabitants, including the children, then we must submit to the wisdom and goodness of God, and acknowledge His wisdom and justice are greater than ours.

Or compare it with the state of Texas Penal Code § 19.02(b)(3) which criminalizes murder (effectively saying "thou shalt not kill"), while at the same time it provides capital punishment ("execution") for convicted murderers. Is that a "textual-discrepancy"?

@RayButterworth  I thought the question was dealing with God's laws? The laws of sinful human governments do not come into this, surely?

@anne - the more Christian a society is the more likely it will impose the death penalty for murder.. that is the historical reality.  It is only anti-God "liberal" societies where governments allow abortion and abolish the death sentence for murderers.  The USA has a much larger %age of Christians than most other countries, and the Texan laws reflect Genesis 9:6 as a consequence.

Noted, and my answer illustrates the OT requirement for God's people to put murderers to death while God sanctions his command for them to wage war against certain groups.

@Anne, my point was it is common for a human government to pass laws that restrict what ordinary citizens may do while retaining the right for itself to do that very thing. And it may very well use ordinary citizens to do it (without penalizing them). We don't consider that a contradiction, so why should anyone consider it a contradiction when God does the same thing? (And I think I originally meant to put that comment on the question, not on this answer.)

You refer to Exodus 20:13 and Deuteronomy 5:17, then claim that God did not go on to add an exclusion clause, such as, "except when commanded by me."
Two points at the outset: (1) Hebrew scholars can clear up the meaning of the word translated "kill" in some translations, but as "murder" in others (e.g. the  N.I.V.). A question about that should be posted in Stack Hermeneutics, and probably has appeared already, but I cannot leave this page to check that out till I've posted this answer.
(2) Not in the verses in question, but elsewhere God absolutely did, and this is verified by Moses who received those ten commandments set in stone. Check out his "Song" in Deuteronomy chapter 32, particularly towards the end. Whatever your view of that sixth commandment, Moses had no doubts about God sanctioning both his war against the nations, and his own people, when they flagrantly violated his laws. Check out the biblical differentiation between murder, and killing, as in Genesis 4:23 where Lamech boasted:

"I have killed a man for wounding me, a young man for injuring me."
N.I.V. where the footnote adds, "Violent and wanton destruction of
human life by one who proclaimed his complete independence from God by
taking vengeance with his own hands" Study Bible, p.15, 1987 edition

Clearly, Lamech committed murder, even though the translation speaks of him "killing" this young man. But not all killing is murder. That is the point.
Another biblical example of how God commands his people to differentiate between killing his enemies in war and individuals who murder, so must be put to death, is in 1 Kings. This relates the eventual killing of one murderer in king David's reign. David did not put him to death at the time, but charged his son, Solomon, to do that. So, justice was eventually carried out on Joab (who was in charge of David's armies). Here is what David commanded Solomon:

"Now you yourself know what Joab... did to the two commanders of
Israel's armies, Abner son of Ner, and Amasa, son of Jethur. He killed
them, shedding their blood in peacetime as if in battle, and with that
blood stained the belt around his waist and the sandals on his
feet..." Then Solomon said:
"Strike him down and bury him, and so clear me and my father's house
of the guilt of the innocent blood that Joab shed. The LORD will repay
him for the blood he shed, because without the knowledge of my father
David he attacked two men and killed them with the sword. Both of them
[Abner and Amasa] were better men and more upright than he. May the
guilt of their blood rest on the head of Joab and his descendants for
ever." 1 Kings 2:5 & 31-33 N.I.V.

Joab was not put to death for leading the armies of God's people where thousands of God's enemies were slaughtered in battle, but for becoming a murderer of two particular men. The distinction here shows that there is no contradiction, as this question asks.

The meaning of the Hebrew words in the text in question have been answered in Hermeneutics in these two links:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/93114/interpretation-of-exodus-2013-scope-of-prohibition-against-killing  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-kill-a-valid-translation-for-exodus-2013-thou-shalt-not-kill
